# Python __slots__ metaclass issue

Tags: python, oop, functional-programming, metaclass, slots

I'm currently implementing slotted metaclasses using `type()`:

```
type(i, (), {'__slots__': tuple(data)
```

I would of course ideally keep with slots as I have a usecase that would benefit from their smaller memory footprint and improved access speed.

when I do:

```
dir(slotted_class)
>>>['__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dir__',
 '__doc__',
 '__eq__',
 '__format__',
 '__ge__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__gt__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__init_subclass__',
 '__le__',
 '__lt__',
 '__module__',
 '__ne__',
 '__new__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__slots__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 'slotted_attribute1',
 'slotted_attribute2',
 'slotted_attribute3',
 'slotted_attribute4']
```

however when I run:

```
slottedclass.slotted_attribute1
```

I get the following error:

```
    >>> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-58-88291109fa74> in <module>()
----> 1 slotted_class.slotted_attribute1

AttributeError: slotted_attribute1
```

EDIT: For further information and even more confusion:
If I implement an equivalent directly without the use of metaclasses:

```
class slottedclass_non_meta(object):
__slots__ = ['slotted_attribute1', 'slotted_attribute2', 'slotted_attribute3', 'slotted_attribute4']

def __init__(self, slotted_attribute1, slotted_attribute2, slotted_attribute3, slotted_attribute4):
    self.slotted_attribute1, self.slotted_attribute2, self.slotted_attribute3, self.slotted_attribute4 = slotted_attribute1, slotted_attribute2, slotted_attribute3, slotted_attribute4
```

Then make this comparison
    dir(slottedclass) == dir(slottedclass_non_meta)

```
>>> True
```

Comment: What's the full error? That looks truncated.

Comment: You did 'slottedClass' Capital C in object instead of 'slotted_class'                      So try this 'slotted_class.slotted_attribute1'

Comment: My apologies that was just a placeholder I wrote for the question itself. However the error is truly that simple. I will add the whole traceback

Comment: Python doesn't actually *support* slots on metaclasses, and unless `i` is `type` or a `type` subclass, you're not making a metaclass at all. It'd be pointless to even try putting `__slots__` on a metaclass anyway, since `type` itself already specifies that its instances have a `__dict__`, and you can't override that from subclasses. Show us a [mcve].

Comment: you can specify that `__dict__` be `__slot__ `: ('1' , '2') however, in order to get a slot when constructing a class with type. I'm asking because I would like to avoid needing to resort to something much less secure (eval/exec) I also have to ask how is providing even an implemetation of the slotted class/ the arguments I used for type() not a complete verifiable example?

Comment: What's `data`? What's `i`? What's `slotted_class`, or `slottedclass`? What's any of this stuff? This isn't complete or verifiable at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably just some error on your `data` variable.  Make
sure it is an iterable or sequence of strings.

Trying this on my interactive environment worked flawlessly:

```
In [162]: m = type("m", (), {"__slots__": ("test1",)})

In [163]: m.test1
Out[163]: <member 'test1' of 'm' objects>

In [164]: n = m()

In [165]: n.test1 = 10

In [166]: n.test1
Out[166]: 10
```

Other considerations there:

- You don't need to talk you are "using metaclasses" for this (though, technically you are) - just say you are creating classes dynamically by calling `type`. On reading the question title most people will think you are trying to specialize `type` itself and include `__slots__` in it.
- On the example code you pasted, you have no `__init__` method fo your dynamically created classes: so you obviusly won't be able to pass the name parameters on class creation and have them set automatically on the instance, as you do on your explicit class.

If the second topic is your problem, I recomend instead of inheriting of `object` (implied but he empty - () - second parameter to call), create a baseclass with a generic `__init__` method to setup the kwargs as attributes:

```
class Base:
   __slots__ = ()
   def __init__(self, **kwargs):
       for key, value in kwargs.items():
           setattr(self, key, value)

slotted_class  = type("slotted_class", (Base,), {"__slots__": ...})
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer, this actually was helpful